# Is there some function which return probability to select prime number from $n$ first Fibonacci numbers.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

So my question is: is there function return probability to select prime number from $n$ first Fibonacci numbers.

So maybe it realize with $\pi(n)$ function?

Comment: Of course there's a function, you've just described it very precisely (its domain is $\mathbb{N}$ and its range is $\mathbb{Q}[0,1]$).

Comment: It might be helpful if you made your question clearer. Presumably, you are hoping for an *algorithm* or a *formula* of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(n)$ is your function, then the question of whether $nf(n)$ is eventually constant is equivalent to the question of whether there exist only finitely many Fibonacci primes.

This is currently an open problem, and likely an extremely difficult one, so there is very little hope for a nice expression for $f(n)$.

Comment: Maybe exist approximate expression

Comment: @openspace Approximate in what sense?  We know, for example, that $F_n$ can only be prime if $n$ is prime, so we have $nf(n)\leq \pi(n)$, in particular $f(n)$ is asymptotically zero.  But any further data about $f(n)$ will depend critically on whether or not there are infinitely many Fibonacci primes.

Comment: Oh I don't know about the former fact.

Comment: @openspace One basic fact about the Fibonacci numbers, provable by induction, is that $(F_m, F_n) = F_{(m,n)}$.  In particular, $F_m$ divides $F_{km}$ for all $k\geq 1$.  We can conclude that if $n$ is composite, $F_n$ is composite.